# Can I drop view but save dependent views?

Tags: postgresql, database-view

I want to drop a view but save dependent views. I just want to update a view's SQL text, but can't do it without deleting it. When I delete it all dependents are deleted. I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to drop the dependent views if `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` doesn't do the trick.

Views are not saved as text, but as parsed queries.

If you don't have the `CREATE VIEW` statements handy, you can use `pg_dump -s` or the `pg_get_viewdef` database function to generate them on the fly.

I cannot refrain from mentioning that a deeply nested hierarchy of views is in my opinion a recipe for trouble.